# Is it ok to use Pika BlockingConnection in web app?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, pika, blockingcollection

I'm a little bit confused about `BlockingConnection` and `AsyncoreConnection`. I want to send some messages to the RabbitMQ queue from a Django app. Is it ok to do that using a global `BlockingConnection` object?

Thank You.

Answer (score 8):

You need to have one `BlockingConnection` object per thread, as stated in the [pika FAQ](http://pika.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#frequently-asked-questions):

> Pika does not have any notion of threading in the code. If you want to
>   use Pika with threading, make sure you have a Pika connection per
>   thread, created in that thread. It is not safe to share one Pika
>   connection across threads.

So, the answer depends on how you're deploying Django. If you're using Django in a multi-threaded deployment, you can't use a global `BlockingConnection`; you need to create one per-thread. If you're not using multi-threading, you can use a global `BlockingConnection` object.

Comment: I don't use threads explicite but deploy django using uWSGI and flags: `enable-threads = true`, `process = 8`. Should I create connection every request? Is there a sense using `pika.SelectConnection` in a synchronous application?

Comment: @User I think that with those settings you'll get 8 single-threaded processes, so you should be able use a global `BlockingConnection`. It doesn't make sense to use a `SelectConnection` because you're not using an event loop in your application. Plus, since you're just using `BlockingConnection` to publish messages (rather than to consume them), you shouldn't be blocking on RabbitMQ calls for very long.